# Auto-Increment Date on new row in Lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a table of Meters.  And then a table of Meter Readings (which has a reference to the Meter table, as well as a column for Date and a column for the reading value). The idea being that for each day one would record the reading for a given meter.  The UI works fine, and I can select a meter, and then click the button to add a new Reading, and a blank "Reading" row gets added to the Readings grid.  The input date for the reading defaults to today.

What I'd like to do is to default the reading date to the last reading date for the specific Meter, + 1 day.  What I envisage is that in the Reading_Created handler, I have pseudocode like this:

```
    var lastDate = DataWorkspace.Data.Readings
                  .Where(r=> r.MeterID == this.MeterID)
                  .Max(r=> r.ReadingDate);
    this.ReadingDate = lastDate.AddDays(1);
```

Is this possible in a Lightswitch app?

Answer (score 1):

If you're adding your new *Reading* using *this.ReadingCollection.AddNew();* then the newly added *Reading* will have its parent *Meter* already correctly set.

Seeing as there's a relationship between *Meter* & its *Readings*, you can leverage that by modifying the code to what's shown below:

```
partial void Reading_Created()
{
    //get parent meter's existing Readings
    var previousReadings = (from r in this.Meter.Readings select r)

    //if previous readings exist for this meter, get the last date, & add a day to it
    if (previousReadings.Any())
    { 
        this.ReadingDate = previousReadings.Max(d => d.ReadingDate).AddDays(1);
    }
    //otherwise, just use today's date
    else
    {
        this.ReadingDate = Date.Today();
    }
}
```

Doing it this way, you don't need to filter the Readings table's records (the relationship does that for you), you don't need to sort them, & you don't need to *TakeOne* (which would fail if there were no records).

Comment: Thanks Yann.  How do I know if I'm adding the new Reading using this.ReadingCollection.AddNew()?  My GUI is a ListAndDetails screen, in which I select a Meter in the List section, then in the details section it displays a grid of Readings for that meter. Then I click in the New Record row in that Details grid.

Comment: Ahh, sorry about that. I was talking about you using AddNew in your own code. In your case LightSwitch is doing the equivalent for you, so the assigning of the parent record will be automatic.

Comment: But it isn't.  As per my response to "Registered User"'s answer, this.MeterID == 0, and this.Meter == null.  Could I be doing something wrong to be getting this behavior?

Comment: How did you create the screen? The "button" that you're clicking to add the new reading record, is it the grid's built-in add button, or one that you've added yourself? It usually really is just an automatic thing, so I'm not sure why it's not working for you. If all else fails, I can guide you through adding your own button, but I want to see how you've created the screen first off.

Answer (score 0):

You could add this code to the Created() event for the entity:

```
partial void Readings_Created()
{
    ReadingDate = (from o in this.DataWorkspace.Data.Readings
                  where MeterID == this.MeterID
                  orderby o.ReadingDate descending
                  select o).Take(1).Execute().Max(o => o.ReadingDate).AddDays(1);
}
```

I tested a similar set of code and it calculated the correct date for the new row.  I did not test if this could would work if there are no entries for the MeterID.

Comment: Ok technically this one works...however, when running it I see that "this.MeterID" is still 0...it is not yet assigned to the created Reading record.  Is there any way that one can get at the selected Meter in the parent Meters grid?

Comment: And what I find odd about the behavior in the above comment is that in the Readings grid, as soon as the new record shows up there, it has the correct MeterId assigned.  So this assigning of the MeterID to the Reading record is happening AFTER the Reading_Created event.  Very sad.

Answer (score 0):

```
   I know this post is older but for anyone researching the method, thanks to Beth Massi vid HDI#20 I came up with this for a similar screen.
```

/*This method fires when the green + button is clicked, looks at selected item in the collection and copies the information from the selected item into the new item being added.*/

```
    partial void Worklists_Changed(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    { 

          if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            if (this.Worklists.Count > 1 & e.NewItems.Count == 1)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Worklist newRecord = (Worklist)e.NewItems[0];
                        Worklist currentRecord = this.Worklists.SelectedItem;

                        newRecord.StartTime = currentRecord.StartTime.Value.AddDays(1);
                        newRecord.EndTime = currentRecord.EndTime.Value.AddDays(1);
                        newRecord.WorklistCode = currentRecord.WorklistCode;
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceInformation("Could not copy data into new row " + ex.ToString());
                    }
                }
        }
     }
```